# Why concatenating two strings is giving error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a text field and an input type submit. When I click on the submit button I should get a url related to the input field. But I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Here's my code that explains more better:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $('#search_btn').click(function() {
            console.log($('#thisiswhatineed').val()); // this is working perfectly
            console.log("<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/ads/search/"); // this is also working perfectly
            var url_to_go = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/ads/search/" . $('#thisiswhatineed').val(); 
            console.log(url_to_go); // this is not working and giving me the error mentioned above
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: concatenating in javascript is done with a + and not with a . like php

Comment: @Rsauxil, you should add that as an answer :) (nevermind, spender beat you too it)

Comment: Yeah maybe I should, but anyway, problem's solved, so who cares now :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, you concatenate strings with `+`, not `.`

So:

```
var url_to_go = 
   "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/ads/search/" + $('#thisiswhatineed').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` operator instead of `.` to concatenate two strings in JavaScript.

Instead of

```
var url_to_go = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/ads/search/" . $('#thisiswhatineed').val();
```

use

```
var url_to_go = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/ads/search/" + $('#thisiswhatineed').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript you use the plus symbol for concatenation.

```
var url_to_go = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/ads/search/" + $('#thisiswhatineed').val();
```

Comment: The dot is also used in Perl (and probably a few other languages as well).

Comment: Edited my answer; removed "used in php" since it's not only php that uses it. :)

Comment: Another side note, PHP is based off of Perl which is why they have similarities such as this.